# Python is this a string or a string array?

Tags: c#, python, porting

I am trying to convert a Python program into C#. I do not understand what is being done here.

```
def mrF(alg, times = 1):
    if ((times % 2) == 0):
        return alg
    else:
        if (alg == 'R'):
            return "L'"
        if (alg[0] == 'G'):
            return alg
        if (alg[-1] == "'"):
            return alg[:-1]
        elif (alg[-1] == '2'):
            return alg
        else:
            return (alg + "'")
```

Is `alg` a string or a string array or a list?

Comment: FWIW, that's very unpythonic python. [No need for any of those parentheses](http://ideone.com/Cr0qCU)

Comment: @Eric Quite true. Also, replacing, for instance, `alg[0] == 'G'` with `alg.startswith('G')` would be more readable. And then there's the cryptic names `alg` and `mrF`, and the fact that this function's purpose is opaque and yet it is uncommented...

Comment: @MarkAmery I did not write this code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a string. You can use a subscript operator on strings in Python, which I assume is the only part in your code, that made you to post it as question.

```
>>> "rohit"[0]
'r'
>>> "rohit"[-1]
't'
>>> "rohit"[0:2]
'ro'
```

Its similar to the way you access indices in `lists`.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning you can do it in C# too (however it's not that flexible) `Console.WriteLine("Hi!"[1]);`

Comment: @Ken.. Actually, I don't have any idea about `C#`. But thanks for mentioning that. :)

Comment: That was a quick one, I have read list stuff on Python. didn't know this could be applied on strings. Thanks!

@Ken , I am not aware I could do that. got to check How I could do [:::] in C#

Comment: @AivanMonceller Do you mean to get a range of characters with the '[] operator'?

Comment: @AivanMonceller You can use [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx).